# Precompiling image takes about 10 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have quite basic image in one of my projects and for some reason, it takes about 10 minutes for my rails app to precompile it. All other images are getting precompiled in few seconds, just this one picture is making troubles. We've tried everything to fix that. Changed compression, extension and even we reproduced the same image in different software but it's allways like that. Here is the image:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any clues!

- ruby 2.0.0-p598
- rails 4.1.0
- sprockets 2.1.13

Comment: does removing the image helps?.. I mean remove it altogether and notice the time..?

Comment: yup. i can basically see in the output that precompilation freezes at this image for 10 minutes.

Comment: have you tried renaming the image?